# Clear OpenTK GL

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering, game-engine, opentk

I'm running multiple games in OpenTK within 1 application.

I'm creating new OpenTK instances for each game, but when you exit it will exit the game and then return to a menu, and dispose of the game instance.

The problem I'm facing is that memory is still accumulated from the previous game that I had exited, and I feel this is due to the textures and everything still loaded into the RAM.

How do I clear this out?
Thanks!

Comment: GL.DeleteTexture(int texID), but without your code, difficult to say more

Comment: How do I get the currently loaded texture ID's?

Comment: Also running through a loop and deleting every texture doesn't doesn't stop the memory accumulation.

Comment: Make sure you `Dispose()` all resources when you no longer need them. For instance, `GameWindow.Dispose()` and/or `GraphicsContext.Dispose()` (depending on how you are using OpenTK).

Comment: Keep in mind that the C# gc is not running immediately, sometimes he decides it's ok for your application to stay at it's current memory level for about half a minute.